# $\gcd(x,y)=1$ then $\gcd(c \cdot x, c \cdot y)=c$ for polynomials

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, polynomial-rings

As a part of a proof I want to use that for polynomials $c, x,y$  it is the case that $\gcd(x,y)=1$ then $\gcd(c \cdot x, c \cdot y)=c$. Is this always true?

Comment: If the polynomials are on the real/complex/rational field, the constant doesn't count, because anything divided by constant is still in the field.

Comment: What does it mean for $x,y$ to have $gcd(x,y)=1?$ Take the definition and see where that leads you..

Comment: Units (invertible elements) don't change the gcd.

Comment: What type of coefficient ring?  Field?

Comment: @lulu The question doesn't state that $c$ is a unit

Comment: @BillDubuque  Ah, true.  Never saw $c$ used as a polynomial name before, but there you are.